# Как собрать объект из входящих данных

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь решить данную задачу уже 4й день (видимо моих знаний js пока еще не хватает)

Итак что мы имеем, есть такой код...

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "cb.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: currencyRate
});


function currencyRate(xml) {

  $(xml).find("Valute").each(function() {

    var currencyID = $(this).attr('ID'); //ID валюты
    var currencyValue = $(this).find("Value").text().replace(',', '.'); //курс валюты

    console.log(currencyID);
    console.log(currencyValue);

  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Код парсит xml файл, (ссылка если что на [XML](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=)) вытаскивает из него текущий курс валют.
Что мне нужно сделать, надо создать объект, по типу...

```js
var currency = {
        R01775: /*ID валюты*/ '70.3548', /*курс валюты*/
        R01760: /*ID валюты*/ '15.0177', /*курс валюты*/
        // итд...
        };
```

или такой объект
CharCode: 'Value'

И дальше уже с этим объектом работать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать объект в коде легко.

```
var object = {};
```

Далее поля в объект динамически добавляются так:

```
object["fieldName"] = value;
```

так как `"fieldName"` это любая строчка, то это присвоение легко сделать в цикле.

Например:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
  object["x"+i] = "value:"+i;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! попробую так тоже.

Comment: @Mistio Это тот-же способ что написал teran, только он написал для конкретного случая, а я объяснил сам синтаксис, теорию.

Comment: @Mistio Если ответ оказался полезным можете поставить UpVote.

Comment: Теория тоже важно! но я сейчас стараюсь больше практики делать

Comment: @Mistio ну в данном случае это та теория которая необходима для практики )) не абстарактная а конкретный метод, то что нужно для понимания как работает динамическое задание свойств.

Answer (score 1):

дак в чем сложность то? вписывайте поля объекта да значения и работайте

```js
var data = '<ValCurs Date="08.12.2017" name="Foreign Currency Market"><Valute ID="R01010"><NumCode>036</NumCode><CharCode>AUD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Австралийский доллар</Name><Value>44,6015</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01020A"><NumCode>944</NumCode><CharCode>AZN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name><Value>34,8793</Value></Valute></ValCurs>';



function currencyRate(xml) {
  var currency = { };
  
  $(xml).find("Valute").each(function() {

    var currencyID = $(this).attr('ID'); //ID валюты
    var currencyValue = $(this).find("Value").text().replace(',', '.'); //курс валюты

    currency[currencyID] = parseFloat(currencyValue);
    

  });
  console.log(currency);
  return currency;
};

currencyRate( $.parseXML(data) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы предлагаете все поля файла в переменную сохранить ? XML - файл динамический, может сменятся постоянно, все зависит от курса валют.  Есть кусок кода на PHP который скачивает этот файл с ЦБ мне на сервер.

Comment: @Mistio Не  все, а нужные. А Вы разве не этого хотели?

Comment: @Mistio не понял вопроса. Если вы про переменную `data`, то это данные взамен  вашего ajax запроса. Если про `currency` то  в вопросе у вас не было указано, какие надо поля или не надо, все валюты из xml

Comment: Может я не так объяснил, сори если что. Еще раз, я хочу все валюты из XML файла засунуть в объект, и уже дальше с этим объектом работать. Вернее мне нужны текущие курсы, а доступ к курсам в объекте будет либо по id либо по CharCode

Comment: @Mistio а приведенный код делает не то же самое? `data` как я уже сказал тут для демонстрации.

Comment: Ага я кажись понял, вы сделали пустой объект а потом строку через parseFloat() засунули туда строку?

Comment: Еще вопрос если можно. А как сделать чтоб объект var currency = { }; был так сказать глобальным ? а то если к нему обращаешся вне функции он пустой...

Comment: @Mistio вынести его объявление на глобальный уровень.

Comment: Вынес, объект пустой... а все заработало! Спасибо за помощь.